# Formula to change 'year''number of days' into mm-dd-year

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, worksheet-function, openoffice.org

I currently was able to split apart a Landsat image for the date information where it was `LC80440142014093LGN00.tar.gz`, and I got it split into `2014093`. Now I need to change that into a date in Excel or Open Office.

So I currently have a number `2014093`, I need to change that into a date format that should be like this `April 4, 2014`.

Comment: Guess I calculated it wrong, you may be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel please try:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,RIGHT(A1,3))
```

Comment: Yep that works for excel :) Thank you, I shall play around now to see if I can get it to work in open office.

Comment: Open office is =DATE((LEFT(F4;4));1;(RIGHT(F4;3))). Maybe a few to many brackets but it works. Thanks for the help again.